# Task "output" the min of :1,2,3,5,6 is 1 / The max of :1,2,3,5,6 is 6 / the max of :1,2,3,5,6 is 3.4

Tags: string, list, max, average, min

Can't get the correct answer on line 3
The avg of 1,2,3,5,6 is 3.4
Closest I get is 3.0

I have tried several different approaches the get the list into a string but I'm missing something small right in front of me

```
    import math
    fileInput = open("input.txt", "r+")
    fileOutput = open("output.txt", "w+")

#Get Min 
    for line in fileInput:
        if "min" in line:
#Remove colons 
            num = line.split(":")
#Get elements at index 1 + 
            line= num[1]
#Remove comma
            lines = line.split(',')
#Use min function to get min 
            minimum = min(lines)
            print(f"The min of {line} is {minimum} \n")
            fileOutput.write(f"The min of {line} is {minimum} \n")
        elif "max" in line:
            num = line.split(":")
            line = num[1]
            lines = line.split(',')
            maximum = max(lines)
            print(f"The max of {line} is {maximum} \n")
            fileOutput.write(f"The max of {line} is {maximum} \n")    
        elif "avg" in line:
            num = line.split(":")
            line = num[1]
            lines = line.split(',')

            average = sum/len(lines)
            print(f"The avg of {line} is {average} \n")
            fileOutput.write(f"The avg of {line} is {average} \n")

    fileOutput.close()


The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4
```

Comment: You're likely doing an integer division, as none of your values are floats. That should give you enough info to google that...

Comment: if a change average = sum/len(lines) to average = sum(map(len,lines)) / len(num) I get 3.5 so that doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

```
Changes to "avg" section

elif "avg" in line:
        num = line.split(":")
        line = num[1]
        lines = line.split(',')

# Convert to float and do calculation
        avr = map(float,lines)
        average = sum(avr) / len(lines)
        print(f"The avg of {line} is {float(average)} \n")
```